# Does Eloquent's createMany method preserves the input array order?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-query-builder

I have `Choice` model which **belongTo** `Question` model which **belongTo** `Quiz` model. To be exact:

- A `Quiz` has exactly 4 `questions`.
- A `Question` has exactly 4 `choices`.

The mentioned relationships are well received in a the `Request` (*showed below*).

---

I need to do all the inserts in three transactions.

I have the following two successful transactions.

```php
DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
    $quiz = Quiz::create(['start_at' => $request->start_at, 'duration' => $request->duration]);
    $questions = $quiz->questions()->createMany($request->questions);
// ...
```

Now **I need the confirmation** that `$questions` **will be similar to** `$request->questions` **in the order of the data** under all circumstances, to rely on that fact and map `id` from the returned collection to the choices from the `Request` as **foreign ids** and do one more bulk insert.

```php
// ...
    $choices = [];
    foreach ($request->questions as $i => $question_data) {
        foreach ($question_data['choices'] as $j => $choice_content) {
            $choices[] = [
                'question_id' => $questions[$i - 1]->id, // Append foreign id
                'content' => $choice_content,
                'choice_number' => $j,
                'is_correct' => $j == $question_data['is_correct'],
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ];
        }
    }
    Choice::insert($choices);
});
```

---

```json
{
    "start_at": "2022-07-17T19:54",
    "duration": "191",
    "questions": {
        "1": {
            "content": "Sed asperiores eaque voluptatem id saepe.",
            "choices": {
                "1": "Ad quia impedit libero voluptatem qui.",
                "2": "Voluptates quis consequuntur natus illum laborum tempore.",
                "3": "Corrupti dolorum optio quam qui.",
                "4": "Numquam quidem voluptatem nisi."
            },
            "is_correct": "4"
        },
        "2": {
            "content": "Illum ut tempora.",
            "choices": {
                "1": "Consequatur minima tempora qui amet.",
                "2": "Voluptate sint sapiente illum delectus possimus enim.",
                "3": "A magni aut aperiam aliquam laboriosam.",
                "4": "Faustino MacGyver"
            },
            "is_correct": "4"
        },
        "3": {
            // ...
        },
        "4": {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's `createMany` does a `foreach` on the array you provide it and returns it in the order that you passed it in. It should retain the order.
This is the source:

```
   public function createMany(iterable $records)
    {
        $instances = $this->related->newCollection();

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $instances->push($this->create($record));
        }

        return $instances;
    }
```

This does not necessarily apply to subsequent queries of that data. That is up to the database how it decides to order it in the absence of an order by clause.

That having been said, you can avoid the entire issue by setting the choices as you create each question. Since you have a relationship, you can allow Laravel to figure out how to set the proper ID's.

```
foreach ($request->questions as $question_data) {

    $question = $quiz->questions()->create([
        // question data here
    ]);

    foreach ($question_data['choices'] as $j => $choice_content) {

        $question->choices()->create(
            [
                // choice data here
            ]
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the definition . So `createMany` still does 4 insert queries which goes against my motivations, I wanted to create the 4 questions in 1 insert. Now I prefer Inserting the question one by one and taking their IDs which guatantees the ordering according to the request

Answer (score 2):

Get the generated SQL.  If there is an `ORDER BY` clause near the end, then the ordering is predictable.  Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the database is free to deliver the results in any order.